# How to keep Photoshop history snapshots?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a design layout in Photoshop, I have several different "snapshots" in my history each with s slight color variation.

I know if I save the file and reopen it, I will only have whatever is current in the history and my snapshots will be lost.

Is there a way to keep my snapshots so I can close Photoshop and then reopen the file and still have all my variations?

Answer (score 5):

You could SAVE A COPY... of the current file, go back one snapshot, SAVE A COPY of that, and repeat going back as far as you want to go.

Comment: I do not feel that this is really a good solutions, I feel that in one file, you want to have multiple snapshots saved for next time that you will open a file.

Comment: @DA01, Are. You. Kidding. Is there an app to automate this task? Otherwise —filesize aside— how *long* will this take?

Answer (score 2):

You can save any snapshot by right clicking on it and save it to new file. That way you can keep certain whatever snapshot you like.

Other way would be, that you create an action that allows you to create a snapshot an make a new file, save this file and close it - all in one "step" (which is, what I usually use).

Answer (score 1):

There's no native way as far as I know that you can keep history of actions taken. It would take a huge amount of memory or disk space too. However, there's a workaround with Layer Comps where you can save different versions of your work effectively. It is not exactly the [same](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/464317), but it is more effective than just trying saving snapshots.

Check out the great lesson of Chris Converse in Lynda of how you use the layer comps.

[Designing the web: Layer Comps](http://www.lynda.com/Photoshop-tutorials/Using-Layer-Comps-Show-Interactive-States/114904-2.html)

Comment: I thonk you should das that Layer comps are a workflow where you keep version of backgrounds. It does not actually have a history.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what you said. History is another matter though, and not in the question really.

Comment: I thought the original question was about history. So I just wanted your answer to be clear.

Comment: fine, just fyi, there's no native way as far as I know that you can keep history of actions taken. It would take a huge amount of memory or disk space too. However, with layer comps you can save different versions of your work effectively. Check it out.

Comment: That's what I meant :)

Comment: I edited my original post. If it helped you, upvote me ;)

Comment: @YannisDran It wouldn't take any more disk space than it takes up in memory. If Photoshop can hold your undo history in 8GB, the file containing undo history will be less than 8GB. Really, it can be smaller; unless you provided several GB of mouse / keyboard / stylus input, storing _your input_ is a lossless way of representing the history.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions out there for this kind of situation is the Visual Versioning in [GridIron Flow](http://www.gridironsoftware.com), which automatically saves versions with thumbnails as you work. Flow solves a lot of other problems as well (such as alerting you when you're about to delete an asset you forgot was included in a project, automatic time sheet tracking, etc.), and makes maps of your projects that show where assets came from and how they relate to one another in an interactive map. I don't know of anything else that is as fast and easy to use for versioning.

Comment: Alan, do you still use Gridiron Flow? Which version do you use, 1 or 2? I've been using it since version 1, and ever since switching to version 2 it's been nothing but problems. I'm wondering if you've had a similar experience (Also, are you running on Mac or Windows? I use Mac). The only reason I haven't gotten rid of Flow is because I can't find a suitable alternative for versioning my CS files. Even so, I don't trust Flow's versioning that much, as I've had issues multiple times where the Flow extension just stopped tracking files, and I didn't realize for a couple weeks.

Comment: I've not had issues with Flow on Win7. I was a beta tester for v1 and v2, and kind of fell in love with the concept right from the start. Do let them know about your problem. Ben Piercey and the rest of the team are very responsive, and they'll want to track down whatever the issue is.

Comment: I'm glad that you haven't had any issues. If it weren't for all the trouble I've had, I would love it too! The concept is great, the execution is good, but Flow 2 has been slow and unstable for me ever since I switched, and I've been using it since it was released. Their support team is very good, they're always helpful, but it seems like as soon as my problem is fixed, another one comes up in its place. It's really frustrating because I WANT to love the program!

Comment: Hey Alan, there's no way to send you a direct message, so I'm going to write here instead. Did you get the email today about Gridiron Flow being discontinued? This is what I hate about "Software as a Service," it sounds like the program is going to become non-functional after December of this year. I'm really upset about this, and I'm wondering what to do.

Comment: Tim -- They're keeping it going for a while, just not selling newly. From what I see, though, the important functions are intact and improved in Filetrek but for a broader audience than Flow was built for. Like everyone, they have to eat, and Flow wasn't the commercial hit they needed it to be to make it viable.