# How to save history in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, cc-2014

Is there a way to save a file in Photoshop CC 2014 with history?
I would like to open a file already saved and see the history.

Comment: This question seems like a possible duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/how-to-keep-photoshop-history-snapshots?rq=1 And I very much wish Photoshop had this feature.

Answer (score 6):

No there is no way to maintain history in a file.

The *only* method is to turn on the  `History log` in the **preferences**. This will merely document the steps you've performed but will not maintain the data in the History panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Photoshop CS or higher you can use the History Log. It will save the file's history to an external file or right inside the PSD.

http://graphicssoft.about.com/cs/photoshop/qt/cshistorylog.htm
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/undo-history.html

Comment: The log file doesn't achieve the effect the OP is asking (i.e. opening the file and being able to revert to previous stages in the history timeline if needed).

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use snaspshots then save each individual snap shots. Then you can look at the 3 or 4 iterations of your file and decide which one you like best.